# LibGDX Box2D Prevent object from slowing down after jumping

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, physics

I'm coding a 2d platformer in libGDX with Box2D, and I just realized that if your object jumps while running and then lands on a surface to continue running, he slows down by like 120% for about a second. That's really annoying, and I can't really come up with a solution. I've tried making the speed higher for a second after the player hits the ground after jumping, but that doesn't really seem to do the trick. This is what I'm using to move the player:

```
    //jumping
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.SPACE) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0){
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 4.2f), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }

    //moving right
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2){
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.17f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }

    //moving left
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2){
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.17f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
```

[Here](https://gameranger.ga/res/libGDX_slow-down-after-jump.mp4) is a video showing what's happening.

I hope I've provided the correct information, please tell me if I haven't.

EDIT: I've also tried setting the position in the x-axis with

```
    player.b2body.setLinearVelocity(1f, 0);
```

but that seems to make the player sort of glide-fly to the right.

Comment: Tried this, but that seems to give another weird result. I've edited my original post, so you can see it there. Thanks!

Comment: @Squiddie Found out the problem with this methode is that I need to set both velocity X and Y, which means the Y has to be affected. I'm sure there is a way to work around that, but I can't really figure out how..

Comment: @Squiddie no, as that resets my velocity in the air when I'm holding down left or right, which makes the Glide-flying effect appear.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look as well

Comment: @Squiddie I came up with a "solution" which, of course, introduced another problem. I simply set the Y to player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().y. This made everything work, except that when I held down right and faced a wall, my player stopped moving, and when I stopped holding it, the player started falling again.